# install gnome desktop in kubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, kubuntu

I am trying to install gnome desktop from kubuntu. So I did this : `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` It ran well but now I am getting this error:

```
sudeep@sudeep:~$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ubuntu-desktop is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 firefox-globalmenu : Depends: firefox (= 20.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.10.3) but it is not going to be installed
 firefox-gnome-support : Depends: firefox but it is not going to be installed
 lightdm-remote-session-uccsconfigure : Depends: firefox but it is not going to be installed
 xul-ext-websites-integration : Depends: firefox (>= 9.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

**EDIT** `sudo apt-get -f install ubuntu-desktop`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.5.0-17 linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  firefox
Suggested packages:
  latex-xft-fonts
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  firefox
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
509 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/24.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 51.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 239358 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking firefox (from .../firefox_20.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.10.3_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/firefox_20.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.10.3_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop', which is also in package kubuntu-firefox-installer 12.04ubuntu1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/firefox_20.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.10.3_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Please help me correct this.

Comment: Did you try running the command suggested in the error messages: `apt-get -f install`?

Comment: Please look at the edit.

Comment: You used the wrong command by specifying the `ubuntu-desktop` package on command line. Use this first: `apt-get -f install` just like the first error message says: `Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages`.

Answer (score 0):

The first command you ran is correct!

It stated that `ubuntu-desktop` is already installed – you need to select it at your Kubuntu login screen.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the package `kubuntu-firefox-installer`.

Comment: Any reason why? Possible downsides?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have Universe and Multiverse repositories enabled.

```
$ su -
# nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Sample output from Xubuntu 12.04 which is precise, make sure those line are uncommented, with the correct release name.

```
Ubuntu 10.04 lucid
Ubuntu 12.04 precise
Ubuntu 12.10 quantal
Ubuntu 13.04 raring

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
```

After make sure you have enabled Universe and Multiverse repositories in /etc/apt/sources.list we now can install gnome.

```
# apt-get update
# apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

ubuntu-desktop package will install full gnome desktop addition softwares like firefox, libreoffice, rhythmbox. If you just want the clean gnome desktop environment without those softwares, you can run this command.

```
# apt-get update
# apt-get install ubuntu-desktop --without-recommends
```

it works for me http://namhuy.net/1584/how-to-install-gui-on-ubuntu-and-linux-mint.html